# how to hide/show field by button for same parent only

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code structure, how do I click the edit button to show/hide the 3 file input fields for that table only?

by default all those file input fields are hidden. 
If I press the edit button inside the second table, only the 3 inputs inside second table will be display.

```
     <table>
        <input type="file" name="product" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="color" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="price" class="editThis" />

        <span class="editButton"></span>
    </table>

    <table>
        <input type="file" name="product" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="color" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="price" class="editThis" />

        <span class="editButton"></span>
    </table>

    <table>
        <input type="file" name="product" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="color" class="editThis" />
        <input type="file" name="price" class="editThis" />

        <span class="editButton"></span>
    </table>
```

most of the examples I found online are using getElementbyID, so I am kind of stuck.

Thanks,

Pat

Comment: Your markup isn't valid (that isn't how you use tables)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be implemented using JQuery, rather than straight Javascript.

EDIT2: Okay, all completely solved! http://jsfiddle.net/3QYhQ/

The Jquery is here:

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
    var x = $(this).attr("group");
    $('.' + x).css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

This says, that any time an `.editButton` is clicked, grab the attribute `group` and take it's value.  Now go found anything that has a class name of whatever value that group had, and make it visible.

```
<input type="button" class="editButton" group="editGroup1" value="Edit" />
<input type="text" name="product" class="editGroup1 editGroup" />
<input type="text" name="color" class="editGroup1 editGroup" />
<input type="text" name="price" class="editGroup1 editGroup" />

<input type="button" class="editButton" group="editGroup2" value="Edit" />
<input type="text" name="product" class="editGroup2 editGroup" />
<input type="text" name="color" class="editGroup2 editGroup" />
<input type="text" name="price" class="editGroup2 editGroup" />
```

Here's the html.  Essentially, all of your hidden inputs have two classes - one binding them to the edit button they'll need to use, and another generic class name that is used by CSS below:

```
.editGroup {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

I hope that helps!

If anyone can do something fancier with `.child()` or something like that (I'm not too well versed on using those), please feel free to share your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3vvR8/2/)

edit

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="product" class="editThis" />
    <input type="file" name="color" class="editThis" />
    <input type="file" name="price" class="editThis" />

    <span class="editButton">edit</span>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="file" name="product" class="editThis" />
    <input type="file" name="color" class="editThis" />
    <input type="file" name="price" class="editThis" />

    <span class="editButton">edit</span>
</div>

$('.editButton').click(function()
                       {
                           $(this).siblings('.editThis').toggle();                                           
                        });
```

Comment: beside the file inputs and edit button, i have like other buttons and inputs inside the same div too, and them all get toggle too. is there a way to just toggle only the one who has the class="editThis" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different class name for each product group of inputs and the use the [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/the_getelementsbyclassname_function.html) function. I would also recommend using `display:none` to remove your `input` elements from the page and then use `display:block` to insert them.

Here is a pure JavaScript example ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yXQnY/9/)):

HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
<th>Product 2</th>
<tr>
    <td id="product_2_edit_button" onclick="my_function()">edit</td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="display:none" type="file" name="product" class="product_2_field" />
            <input style="display:none" type="file" name="color" class="product_2_field" />
            <input style="display:none" type="file" name="price" class="product_2_field" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
function my_function() {
var testing = document.getElementsByClassName("product_2_field");
testing[0].style.cssText = "display:block";
testing[1].style.cssText = "display:block";
testing[2].style.cssText = "display:block";
```

}